# Update JobExecution db record inside the afterJob()

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have got into a situation when job state which is passed into the `JobExecutionListener.afterJob()` method has `FINISHED` job execution state, however when I go and check the same `JobExecution` inside the batch db schema I see that the job state is still set to `RUNNING`.

I need both of them to be in sync.

Is there any way to have this? Can I safely update the batch database with the passed JobExecution instance inside my afterJob () method using JobRepository directly? Any side effects for this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is correct behavior as listener method -
 `JobExecutionListener.afterJob()` is hooked once job is finished in memory but repository is yet to be updated for final job status.

Correct status needs to be available in that method because usually some post processing kind of logic is executed there based on that status - like releasing some resources , sending some emails etc.

Updating status to repository would be final thing while you might like that status in repository to something else ( based on certain conditions ) like I do ,

```
if (zeroRead) {
    jobExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
    return;
 }
```

If reader has not found any records while reading, framework marks job status as `FAILED` while that is a perfectly normal situation for me.

Even if you update status from there, framework would still try to update again so there would be a repetition.

Even though its not a good idea to update repository on your own but I guess you need to explain more about - **I need both of them to be in sync** to understand your requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

From the [SpringBatch source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/job/AbstractJob.java),I can see that it should be ok to update this status there.

However my personal opinion on that is that we should try to avoid the situation when we modify the data for the framework directly.

We can not know what can of changes might be introduced into SpringBatch after and what kind of side effect it might lead to.