# How to catch two Spring Batch jobs are completed?

Tags: spring, kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have two Spring Batch jobs. Let's assume that two jobs are called `AJob` and `BJob`. I want to do something after these two jobs are executed successfully. I was trying to publish kafka messages in both `afterJob` methods of two jobs, and a consumer checks the exit statuses of two jobs and do the main business logic.

However, the main business logic code doesn't always seem to work. I found a comment in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109733/21256049).

> JobExecutionListener.afterJob() is hooked once job is finished in memory but repository is yet to be updated for final job status.

In this situation, what is the best practice? I want to ensure two jobs are completely executed and then do the main business logic.

```
@Configuration
class AJobConfiguration() {
  @Bean
  @JobScope
  fun jobExecutionListener(): JobExecutionListener {
    return object : JobExecutionListenerSupport() {
      override fun afterJob(jobExecution: JobExecution) {
        // publish kafka message
      }
    }
  }
}
@Configuration
class BJobConfiguration() {
  @Bean
  @JobScope
  fun jobExecutionListener(): JobExecutionListener {
    return object : JobExecutionListenerSupport() {
      override fun afterJob(jobExecution: JobExecution) {
        // publish kafka message
      }
    }
  }
}

// consumer
@KafkaListener()
fun finishJobs() {
  val isAFinished = jobExplorer.getLastJobExecution(JobAInstance).exitStatus.exitCode == ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode
  val isBFinished = jobExplorer.getLastJobExecution(JobBInstance).exitStatus.exitCode == ExitStatus.COMPLETED.exitCode
  if (isAFinished && isBFinished) {
    // do something <- This doesn't works sometimes.
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't make your kafka listener on one topic? Produce to two different topics and join them. On a join, you're guaranteed both event exist. Otherwise, you're needlessly processing Kafka events twice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message to Kafka after **both** jobs are executed, you should not do it in `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` of each job (this will send two messages to Kafka and is not what your are looking for).

You did not share how you are running these jobs, but to keep it simple this could be done in the `main` method after both jobs have been executed sequentially successfully.

Another option is to use the [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) to create a job of jobs:

- Step 1: of type `JobStep` that runs `AJob`
- Step 2: of type `JobStep` that runs `BJob`
- Step 3: of type `TaskletStep` that sends a message to kafka

If you like this job of jobs idea, then you can also send the message in a `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` that you register on the global job (meaning this listener will be executed after **both** jobs have run successfully).

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, There is a requirement that the two operations should not be performed sequentially.

Comment: That requirement was not explicitly mentioned in the initial question. But good to see you solved your issue.